NavigationStack and TabView causes screen misalignment
We have installed a TabView in our NavigationStack and have encountered the following problem.
Probrem1: After transitioning from FristPage() to NextPage(), the screen behaves as if it is shifted in the y direction (downward).
Problem2: When swiping vertically in NextView(), the screen phase shifts in the y-direction (upward).
When Problem1 occurs, the screen Rectangle() is centered and the screen is temporarily in the desired state, but when Problem2 occurs, the screen Rectangle is out of view downwards and does not look good.
If you have a solution, please let me know.
struct FirstView: View {
  @State var isNextView = false
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      VStack {
        Button {
          isNextView.toggle()
        } label: {
          Text("go next page")
        }
      }
      .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isNextView, destination: {
        NextView()
          .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      })
    }
  }
}

struct NextView: View {
  let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
  let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
  
  @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
  
  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      Rectangle()
        .frame(width: width, height: height)
        .foregroundColor(.red)

       Rectangle()
        .frame(width: width, height: height)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: .center)
    .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .safeAreaPadding(0)
    //      .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        Button {
          dismiss()
        } label: {
          Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


This may be a symptom of having a TabView nested inside a NavigationStack. Usually, they are used the other way around.
I couldn't find a workaround for the shifting issues. However, since the page indicators for the TabView are hidden, a possible alternative would be to use a ScrollView instead of the TabView. If you apply .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging) then it behaves very similarly.

Use an HStack with spacing: 0 as the container for the subviews.
Apply .scrollTargetLayout() to the HStack, to work with the scrollTargetBehavior on the ScrollView.
Use .containerRelativeWidth(.horizontal) to set the width of the subviews to the full screen width.

// struct NextView

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Red page")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                .background(.red)
            Text("Blue page")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                .background(.blue)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .toolbar {
        // same as before
    }
}



Answer updated with a much simpler alternative: a ScrollView with scrollTargetLayout
